# PySpark: printing to terminal inside while loop

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm starting to learn Spark by myself, so my question could be really silly.

Anyways, I'm working on an example provided by Spark installation (link: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/kmeans.py)

And I want to modify a little bit the code since I need to better understand the map-reduce operations.

What I'm trying to do is:

```
while tempDist > convergeDist:
    print('Here \n')
    closest = data.map(
        lambda p: (closestPoint(p, kPoints), (p, 1)))
    print(closest)
    pointStats = closest.reduceByKey(
        lambda p1_c1, p2_c2: (p1_c1[0] + p2_c2[0], p1_c1[1] + p2_c2[1]))
    print(pointStats)
    newPoints = pointStats.map(
        lambda st: (st[0], st[1][0] / st[1][1])).collect()
```

However, none of the above print is actually printed when executing the script with the command

```
 spark-submit kmeans.py
```

While instead later

```
 print("Final centers: " + str(kPoints))
```

Is actually printed to terminal.

Can someone help me understand why?

Answer (score 0):

`closest` and `pointStats` , both are rdds, when you do print statement on rdds, you can only see statement like `PythonRDD[36] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:48` printed at terminal. Their contents will not get printed unless you issue `action` on the rdd like -

```
print(closest.collect())
```

The statement `print("Final centers: " + str(kPoints))` works because 
kPoints is generated using `action` `takeSample` -

```
kPoints = data.takeSample(False, K, 1)
```

Hope this helps. Please read more on difference between actions and transformation operations of rdds.